# How to pass data in state from one component to other in different folder?

Tags: reactjs

I have two components. First is register where I input data, and second is Login where only user that registered can Login. This is my code:

regis.js

```js
class Register extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userData: [],
            fullName: "",
            email: "",
            uname: "",
            pass: "",
            passval: ""
        }
    }

    onChangeInput = e => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    onRegis = () => {
        const { fullName, email, uname, pass, passval } = this.state

        if(pass !== passval){
            alert("Check your password!")
        } else {
            const userData = [...this.state.userData]
            userData.push({
                'fullName': fullName,
                'email': email,
                'uname': uname,
                'pass': pass
            })
            this.setState({ userData })
            // console.log("Datanya euy: ", userData)
        }
    }
    
    render() { 
        return (
            <div className="regis">
                <form className="regis-form" method="POST" name="regist">
                    <div className="container-log">
                        <h1 className="judul">Registrasi</h1>
                        <RowInput value={this.props.fullName} label="Full Name" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" name="fullName" onChange={this.onChangeInput}/>
                        <RowInput value={this.props.email} label="E-mail" placeholder="E-mail" type="text" name="email" onChange={this.onChangeInput}/>
                        <RowInput value={this.props.uname} label="Username" placeholder="Username" type="text" name="uname" onChange={this.onChangeInput}/>
                        <RowInput value={this.props.pass} label="Password" placeholder="Password" type="password" name="pass" onChange={this.onChangeInput}/>
                        <RowInput value={this.props.passval} label="Ulangi Password" placeholder="Re-enter Password" type="password" name="passval" onChange={this.onChangeInput}/>
                        <Button onClickInput={this.onRegis}>Regis</Button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

login.js

```js
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: "",
            password: "",
            userSession: []
        }
    }

    onChangeInput = e => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    onLogin = () => {
        const { username, password } = this.state
        const userSession = []

        for (let i = 0; i < this.props.userData.length; i++) {
            if (this.props.userData[i][3] === username && this.props.userData[i][2] === password) {
                userSession.push(userData[i])
            }
            
        }

        console.log(username, ": ", password);
    }
```

When I try to change `this.state` in regis to `this.props` I got error, either the value in array become undefined, or `userData not defined`. But when I use this code, i got error in login `userData is not defined`.

I'm sorry I hope I can explain better but english is not my first language and this is my first time using ReactJS. Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the code sample of  `render` method in Regis.js ?

Comment: Ok, done. You can check it in Regis.js

Comment: Why do you even wanna change `this.state` to `this.props`? It doesn't work like that.

Comment: We use `props` to access data which are coming from parent component. But in your scenario, you are not passing data from `regis.js` to `login.js`. You can pass data from either `router` or else you can use `context` api

Comment: what's mean `{this.props.fullName}` .?change to `{this.state.fullName}` and other.

Comment: @AmilaDulanjana sorry, do you have any simple example/exaplanation how to use context api? because (even after my research), i still dont understand how to use it and where should i put it